# Import sip client module to appcelerator error

Tags: android, sip, appcelerator

I'm trying to implement SIP client call to accelerator project. After a few hours of Googling, I decided to use [TISIPCLIENT](https://github.com/dbankier/TiSIPClient-Android) .

So I imported the module to my project. But now I am facing one big problem. I keep getting the error **createSipclient** method not found.

Here is my code:

```
var sipclient = require("com.yydigital.sipclient");

var sip = sipclient.createSipclient({

// Events
onregistering : function() {
//callback
}, onregisterationfailed : function() {
//callback
}, onregistrationdone : function() {
//callback
}, oncallestablished : function() {
//callback
}, oncallended : function() {
//callback
}, onincomingcall : function(e) {
//callback
}, onringingback : function() {
//callback
}, oncallbusy : function() {
//callback
}, onerror : function(e) {
    //callback
}
});
```

What could be the cause of the error and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By seeing your error "createSipclient method not found."...
It seems like the module is not able to locate the proxy. Try to rebuild the module and use it, this will definitely solve your problem since i had faced many times the same error and i did the same to solve the issue. 
Let me know if that works else we will look in other way.